# Uncaught Error: noUiSlider (10.0.0): must pass a formatter for all handles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need four slide holder with tooltips. When I try 3 then it works, but when I try 4 then it shows the following error:

> Uncaught Error: noUiSlider (10.0.0): must pass a formatter for all
>   handles

My code

```
noUiSlider.create(handlesSlider4, {
    start: [4000, 8000, 12000, 16000],
    connect: [false, true, false, true, false],

    tooltips: [false, wNumb({ decimals: 1 }), true],

    range: {
        'min': [2000],
        'max': [20000]
    }
});
```

Missing tooltip
screenshot 
http://prntscr.com/hh66qy
updated code

```
  noUiSlider.create(handlesSlider4, {
          start: [4000, 8000, 12000,16000],
          connect: [false, true, false, true,false],

          //  tooltips: [false, wNumb({ decimals: 1 }), true],
        tooltips: [false, wNumb({ decimals: 1 }), true, false],

          range: {
              'min': [2000],
              'max': [20000]
          }
      });
```

How I can see tooltip on all handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the same number of hanldes (*`start`*) and the formatters (*`tooltips`*).

So, if you are using 4 `start` handles, `tooltips` should also have a length of 4.

```
 ...

 // add a 4th input here, I have used `false` but use as per your requirement
 tooltips: [false, wNumb({ decimals: 1 }), true, false],

 ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it worked but now I cannot see tooltips on handle above.

Comment: Isn't it because you are using `false` as first and fourth element in the  `tooltips` array?